# Custom hardware color dependent wallpaper on network imaged iMacs

Tags: macos, network, imac

I have a set of new iMacs. If you go into the **About This Mac** ▶ **Displays**, there's a drawing of the computer in the same color as the computer actually is. This is in spite of the fact that the computers have all been given the same image over a network using [Jamf](https://www.jamf.com/lp/apple-mobile-device-management-mdm-jamf).

So somehow, each computer "knows" what color it is. With this in mind, is there a way to assign each computer a different wallpaper according to the body color? Similar to the wallpapers they shipped with, but I want to use my own different colored images instead of the ones that came with it.

Of course, I can change the wallpaper manually, but these computers are at a library so the change will only stay for the individual network login. I'd like to make it so that all users who log in to the computer get a color-assigned wallpaper by default.

I have no idea if this is possible but that's why I'm asking :)

Comment: Interesting. Do you have the ability to script a single desktop background or use an MDM?

Comment: Jamf is an MDM, I think anyway

Comment: Yes - jamf has two MDM suites